# Search and remove object from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to search a object and remove from json array

my json array of object looks like

```
var data = [{
    {id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"},
    {id: "2", name: "Witches of Eastwick", type: "comedy"},
    {id: "3", name: "X-Men", type: "action"},
    {id: "4", name: "Ordinary People", type: "drama"},
    {id: "5", name: "Billy Elliot", type: "drama"},
    {id: "6", name: "Toy Story", type: "children"}
}];
```

What I am try to achieve is if I have a object with Id=1
I can search the array match it with array  and remove it from the array.

I am trying this by below code

```
function RemoveNode(id)
{
 data.forEach(function (emp) {
   if(emp.Id == id)
    {
      delete emp;
    }
  }
}
```

I am not able to get it work, kindly suggest a better way to do this

Comment: You're using not valid data structure

Comment: your data is not valid. either an array or an object, but the property is missing

Comment: ok can you please explain by saying data is not valid.....

Comment: @ankur `data` should be either an array (`var data = [...]`) or an object with a property (`var data = {arr:[..]}`). Currently it is an object *without* a property name!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using not valid data structure, your array needs to be in square brackets `[]`

For your case better to use `filter` function:

```js
var data = [
    {id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"},
    {id: "2", name: "Witches of Eastwick", type: "comedy"},
    {id: "3", name: "X-Men", type: "action"},
    {id: "4", name: "Ordinary People", type: "drama"},
    {id: "5", name: "Billy Elliot", type: "drama"},
    {id: "6", name: "Toy Story", type: "children"}
];

function RemoveNode(id) {
    return data.filter(function(emp) {
        if (emp.id == id) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}

var newData = RemoveNode("1");

document.write(JSON.stringify(newData, 0, 4));
```

Comment: You can directly do `return emp.id != id`. Look for @Jamiec's answer

Comment: @Rajesh yeah, I see, thanks. Maybe my code more explains the logic of filter method, without magic

Comment: @isvforall if I want to select a particular node based on the id , like let say id = 3; it will give me a object  {id: "3", name: "X-Men", type: "action"},
and I can do some business operation on it so how can I find this.

Comment: @ankur *so how can I find this* find what? an index of that object in an array?

Comment: @isvforall  want the object in a variable like var single = //do some operation to get the object in single. so If I do   single. id it gives me value 3 and single.name  will give me x-men...

Comment: @ankur - thats the exact *opposite* of what your question asked!

Comment: @ankur yes, can access to object data via `.` dot notation e.g. `single.id` or `single. name`, *can do some business operation on it* - yes

Comment: @Jamiec yaa this is for some thing else not for the question

Answer (score 4):

A better way might be to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your original array to remove the item you dont want.

Assuming `data` is really an array of objects (ie, does not have the error currently in your question)

```
function RemoveNode(id){
    return data.filter(function(e){
        return e.id !== id;
    });
}
```

You could also use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), however that would require knowing the *index* of the item you want to remove, and by the time you've found that you may as well just `filter`!

Answer (score 1):

Consider this following code with `forEach` & `splice`, assuming `data` is array of objects:

```
var data = [
    {id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"},
    {id: "2", name: "Witches of Eastwick", type: "comedy"},
    {id: "3", name: "X-Men", type: "action"},
    {id: "4", name: "Ordinary People", type: "drama"},
    {id: "5", name: "Billy Elliot", type: "drama"},
    {id: "6", name: "Toy Story", type: "children"}
];

function RemoveNode(id){
    data.forEach(function(e, index){
    if(id == e.id){
        data.splice(index, 1);
    }
  })
}
RemoveNode(1);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

using jquery you can do like this

```
function RemoveNode(id)
{

 $.each(data,function (key,val) {
   if(val.Id == id)
    {
      delete data[key];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There was absolutely no need for JQuery in this answer! All that burdon for `$.each`!

Comment: Why do you need to use jQuery? Can't you do the same thing with `data.forEach`?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use delete from array and not current iteration.

You can try this:

```js
var data = [
    {id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"},
    {id: "2", name: "Witches of Eastwick", type: "comedy"},
    {id: "3", name: "X-Men", type: "action"},
    {id: "4", name: "Ordinary People", type: "drama"},
    {id: "5", name: "Billy Elliot", type: "drama"},
    {id: "6", name: "Toy Story", type: "children"}
];

data.forEach(function(emp, index){
  if(emp.id==1){
    delete data[index];
  }
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(data,0,4) + "</pre>")
```

Also if you want to remove value based on condition, you should try `Array.filter`

```js
var data = [
  {id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"},
  {id: "2", name: "Witches of Eastwick", type: "comedy"},
  {id: "3", name: "X-Men", type: "action"},
  {id: "4", name: "Ordinary People", type: "drama"},
  {id: "5", name: "Billy Elliot", type: "drama"},
  {id: "6", name: "Toy Story", type: "children"}
];

var result = data.filter(function(emp){ return emp.id != 1 });

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result,0,4) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in combination with [`Array#splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
var data = [{ id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime" }, { id: "2", name: "Witches of Eastwick", type: "comedy" }, { id: "3", name: "X-Men", type: "action" }, { id: "4", name: "Ordinary People", type: "drama" }, { id: "5", name: "Billy Elliot", type: "drama" }, { id: "6", name: "Toy Story", type: "children" }];

function del(id) {
    var index;
    data.some(function (a, i) {
        if (a.id === id) {
            index = i;
            return true;
        }
    }) && data.splice(index, 1);
}

del('1');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: If there are more than one matching elements, this will only remove one of them.

Answer (score 0):

**You must assign the array to a key in your object/json.**

Then use filter to make a condition on every object!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Code:

```
var data = {"data": [
    {"id": 1, "name": "New York"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Dubai"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Brabrand"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Anything"}
]}.data;

var removeId = 2

var newData = data.filter(function(object) {
  return object.id !== removeId;
}) 

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: I guess this is not what OP is looking.